# Document!X To accomplish this action, set property AssemblyName

Tags: document

I am new to using Document!X and am receiving the following error when building the contents of my database

> "To Accomplish This action, Set Property AssemblyName"

[image: Snip of error]

I guess the error speaks for itself - Set the property AssemblyName, but I don't know where the settings are for setting the assembly name.

Please could someone instruct me on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is a compatibility issue, Document!X 2011 cannot create databse builds for SQL Server 2012.